# Reset counter ID to 1 for every new year in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables , `tblContacts` and `tblTrackJob`. Every time a new record is about to be added in `tblContacts` , id like to assign its `JobNo` field to the value of whatever `ID` is in `tblTrackJob` has stored. Id like the value to reset to 1 every year.

For example...

```
 first name, last name, JobNo, dateEntered
 bob         smith       01    1/1/2013
 john        doe         02    1/2/2013
 mary        Thomas      03    1/3/2013

 Joe         Henry       01    1/1/2014
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It looks like you want new [tblContacts] records to be assigned a sequential [JobNo] based on the year that they were created (reset to 1 for each new year) so how does [tblTrackJob].[ID] factor into this? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @GordThompson The 'tblTrackJob' table contains the counter for the next 'JobID' that I will call to populate the 'JobID' field in the 'tblContracts' table.

Comment: If [tblTrackJob] will just hold a single "NextID" counter that will get reset to 1 for each new year then you don't really need to do it that way. You can just base the next [JobNo] value on MAX()+1 of the existing [JobNo] values in [tblContacts] for that year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're dealing with Access 2010 we can create a `Before Change` [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) for the [tblContacts] table to assign the [JobNo] value:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

The macro will find the largest [JobNo] in the table from records with a corresponding `Year([dateEntered])`, and then add 1 to that value to give us the [JobNo] for the new record. If no existing records are found for the corresponding year then the new record gets a [JobNo] equal to 1.

Comment: Just curious: why doing it with a macro instead of VBA ? Anyway it's interesting, since it made me discover that those "new" macros seem to handle variables, and are quite readable finally.

Comment: @iDevlop The main advantage is that the data macro will run regardless of how the table gets updated, so even if a user opens the table in Datasheet View and adds a record the macro will still be executed.

Comment: ok...matching SQL Server's triggers. Got it. Thanks ! I will definitely have to digg this someday.